# Slack API, how to get user scopes for a bot?

Tags: slack-api

I am unable to grant user scopes to my bot. I've successfully set up an OAuth flow and got bot scopes, but when I try to add user scopes my oauth flow will error out with a generic error "There was something wrong with your request".

It seems like I cannot combine slack bot scopes with user scopes in the same app? This is using the latest API which prioritizes granular bot scopes over workspace wide scopes.

How can I combine user scopes with bot scopes?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Which users scopes specifically are your trying to add?